# An unhandled exception occurred: The requested module 'sourcemap-codec' does not provide an export named 'decode'

Tags: angular, source-maps, angular-upgrade, angular13

On Upgrading, to angular 13, My build step on pipeline is failing. My initial version was 11, on upgrading to 12 the build worked fine but on upgrading from 12 to 13, it started giving me this error on pipeline. The build is running fine on local but failing on pipeline.

I have also added the package.json file code and dependencies and also added the image that displays error.

```
[![{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:prod": "ng serve -c production",
    "start:local": "ng serve -c local",
    "start:test": "ng serve -c local,test",
    "start:ci": "serve -s --no-clipboard --listen ${PORT:-4200} ",
    "build": "ng build",
    "updateVersion": "node ./updateVersion.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage --ci",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .js,.ts,.html",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "e2e:prod": "ng e2e --headless --configuration production",
    "e2e:parallel": "npx cy2 run --record --key gitlab-ci --parallel --ci-build-id 1",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^13.2.5",
    "@mat-datetimepicker/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^11.1.1",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^11.1.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^11.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^11.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "cypress-get-table": "^1.0.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngrx-forms": "^6.3.4",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "tsify": "^5.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "yargs-parser": "^18.1.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1302.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.2.5",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^15.0.0",
    "@cypress/browserify-preprocessor": "^3.0.1",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^10.1.2",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "^12.4.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.15",
    "@types/chai-as-promised": "^7.1.3",
    "@types/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/faker": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.14",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "axe-core": "^4.2.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "commitlint": "^15.0.0",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "cy2": "^1.2.1",
    "cypress": "7.6.0",
    "cypress-axe-core": "^1.1.3",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.2.0",
    "cypress-fail-on-console-error": "^2.1.0",
    "cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.4.0",
    "cypress-pipe": "^2.0.0",
    "cypress-terminal-report": "^3.2.2",
    "eslint": "^8.10.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.6.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.8.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-fail-on-console": "^2.0.4",
    "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "8.4.0",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    "mocha": "^8.3.2",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "mochawesome": "^6.2.2",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^1.18.0",
    "ng-cache-testing-module": "^1.1.3",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.3.2",
    "serve": "^11.3.2",
    "source-map": "^0.6.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "output/coverage/jest",
    "reportFile": "test-report.xml"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "resetMocks": false,
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": \[
      "<rootDir>/setupJest.ts",
      "jest-localstorage-mock"
    \],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": \[
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/dist/",
      "<rootDir>/src/test.ts"
    \],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
      "@core/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/core/$1",
      "@material/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/material/$1",
      "@features/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/features/$1",
      "@testing/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/testing/$1",
      "@shared/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/shared/$1",
      "@environments/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/environments/$1"
    },
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfig": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.html$",
        "astTransformers": \[
          "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer"
        \]
      }
    }
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E  HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,html}": "eslint --cache --fix"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
    "stepDefinitions": "./e2e/features/",
    "cucumberJson": {
      "generate": true,
      "outputFolder": "output/cucumber-json",
      "filePrefix": "",
      "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
    }
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "outputDirectory": "output",
    "outputName": "junit.xml"
  }
}][1]][1]
```

The sourcemap-codec latest version is 1.4.8 and it is added as dependency in package.lock file automatically but still it only fails on pipeline and works fine on my local.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing the same issue which is why I stumbled across this post.

My issue was I was using the wrong node version.
I faced a similar issue after upgrading to **Angular 13** but I was using node version **v14.2.0.**

[image]

I changed the node version to **v14.15.0** and it worked.

`nvm use v14.15.0`

PS: [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) manages multiple nodejs versions.